# Database processing: Best way to handle concurrency from plugins

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, plugins, concurrency

I want to create a plug in and run it in more than one machine doing exact same thing: processing records. I want the 1st plugin to get let's say a batch of a 1000 but I want the second plug in to get a batch of next 1000, starting at I'd 1001 to 2000. What would be the best way to do this? I want to use entity framework. I don't one one plug in to wait on the other. I want o e to take its 1000 and process it and the other to take its 1000 and process it. I use a while loop take next 1000.

Comment: Distributed systems: reliable, fast, consistent: pick *two*. The answer will depend on which two you pick.

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer?  I mean, how would you implement it?

Comment: That is a comment not an answer. I am requesting clarification of your requirements (based on a well known saying).

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear

Comment: To test this I tried using parallel.for each task and no errors but it seems more sequential.